# macOS Time announcement -- how to speak a longer phrase

Tags: macos, big-sur, system-settings

In macOS (Big Sur), ever since I did:

```
defaults write ./com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs TimeAnnouncementPrefs -dict u -bool YES
```

the system announces the time as, for example, "four-thirty," whereas it used to announce the time as "It's four-thirty" (with the word "it's" and, on the hour, "o-clock").

Here's the prefs structure (`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs`):

```
{
    TimeAnnouncementsEnabled = 1;
    TimeAnnouncementsIntervalIdentifier = EveryQuarterHourInterval;
    TimeAnnouncementsPhraseIdentifier = ShortTime;
    TimeAnnouncementsVoiceSettings =     {
        CustomVolume = "0.2046729";
    };
 }
```

I've tried:

1. With and without `TimeAnnouncementsPhraseIdentifier`.
2. Deleting the file `com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs` and then turning on the time-anounce checkbox in System Preferences.  That restores the file, but not the long speech.
3. Using Time Machine to restore an old version of `com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs`.

After each change, I've killed the Dock to reload the preferences.

How do I get back the "it's" and "o'clock" wording?  What values can `TimeAnnouncementsPhraseIdentifier` take on?

Edit: here's the System Preferences pane:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

1. (Optional) to get the plist in `com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs` correct, set the structure as shown in my original question.  Or, simply delete that file and turn on the Time Announce checkbox in System Preferences (Dock & Menu Bar, Clock).  That will re-create the file.
2. In the two `defaults` commands, use `-dict-add` (rather than `-dict`) so the commands won't delete any existing parameters.  At this point, the defaults command can be used to turn the time announcements on and off.  But, "it's" and "o-clock" are still missing.
3. Reboot, and "it's" and "o'clock" will return.  I still don't know what values `TimeAnnouncementsPhraseIdentifier` can take on, but ShortTime works (after a reboot).

But, my original idea of using `defaults write` to change the plist didn't work anyway.  The changes do not take effect without a reboot because the OS caches the plist.